# Using Bluetooth low energy in linux command line

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I am working on using the Bluetooth low energy modem with Linux. I am using the command line option for that i.e. `hcitool` .  I am able to the find the devices using the command: `$ hcitool scan`

It is working fine for me, also I am able to broadcast my device using :

```
 sudo hciconfig hci0 leadv
```

It is also working fine.  But I want to add the services and characteristic to the modem device which can be detected by other device.  I have tried `sdptool add` but it is not working for me. Does anyone know how to add the services and characteristics to the peripheral using the command line tools in ubuntu?

**Edit:** My modem is broadcasting but not able to explore the services and characteristic to the other BLE device.  Now I am able to set the name of device using `hcio name command`

**Edit:** Now I am able to render the services and characteristic, by simultaneously running `sudo hcidump` command.  But I am not able to track from where I am getting those services and characteristics. One definite observation is those services are rendering from the machine.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's anything in Bluez to simulate a GATT server.  (I tried looking in the past and couldn't find one)  SDP is regular non-LE bluetooth, so it's not there.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

SDP is absent in BLE. Broadcast/advertise frame and GATT client/server are used instead.

Several links:

- [BlueZ **gatttool**: command line tool to run common GATT procedures](http://www.bluez.org/bluez-low-energy-support-status/)
- [BlueZ GATT's ready profiles](http://www.bluez.org/profiles/)
- [hint: DBUS](http://www.ioncannon.net/linux/1570/bluetooth-4-0-le-on-raspberry-pi-with-bluez-5-x/)
- [**GATT and DBUS example**](http://i-miss-erin.blogspot.com/2011/09/bt-le-findme-profile-in-bluez.html)
- [How can I connect to the FitBit Zip over Bluetooth 4.0 LE on Linux with bluez?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666294/how-can-i-connect-to-the-fitbit-zip-over-bluetooth-4-0-le-on-linux-with-bluez)
- [Bluetooth Low Energy: listening for notifications/indications in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657007/bluetooth-low-energy-listening-for-notifications-indications-in-linux)
- http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.bluez.kernel/29547

Comment: Minimal introduction: http://www.imd.uni-rostock.de/ma/gol/lectures/embedded/Literatur/Low%20Energy%20Training.pdf

http://chapters.comsoc.org/vancouver/BTLER3.pdf

http://www.glynstore.com/content/docs/bluegiga/BLE_getting_started.pdf

Remember to distinguish Bluetooth classic, single mode (Bluetooth Smart, ie. LE) and dual mode (Smart Ready) devices.

Comment: one more related: http://i-miss-erin.blogspot.com/2010/12/gatt-related-dbus-api.html and http://i-miss-erin.blogspot.com/2010/12/gatttool-in-bluez-over-bredr.html

Comment: GATT definitions: https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/Pages/default.aspx To track characteristic you have to turn on notify or indication flag in Characteristic Configuration if allowed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657007/bluetooth-low-energy-listening-for-notifications-indications-in-linux

Comment: Let's note that 2 bytes of the characteristic are swapped (Big/Little Endian issue).

Answer (score -2):

I used to broadcast BT services by following this [article](http://www.drdobbs.com/mobile/using-bluetooth/232500828). This page not only shouws you how to advertise a profile, but also gives you an example on how to implement the HSP profile.

To know the bt class you need to announce, you can check this other [page](http://bluetooth-pentest.narod.ru/software/bluetooth_class_of_device-service_generator.html).

Comment: I think all of that applies only to standard bluetooth, not LE.

Comment: This does not work with Bluetooth Low Energy, it is for standard Bluetooth, as Tim said. SDP and all that is implemented as GATT in BLE.