# Example code to access battery service from ble device in C using bluez

Tags: c, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, gatt, hci

I have a ble device which gives battery status as battery service.I need to read battery information from my ble device using C programming language from linux using bluez. I could not see a proper example anywhere for this purpose even though there are examples of classic bluetooth. I am able to detect my ble device using the example code [here](https://github.com/carsonmcdonald/bluez-experiments/blob/master/experiments/scantest.c).
How can I connect to my device ( I have the device address after scanning ) ?
How can I request the battery service to my device ( I know the service handle for my battery service ) ?
Expecting Example code.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have example code but I can point you to the source code similar to what you did. To read the battery service you'll need the following steps:-

1. As you mentioned, **scan** and detect the address that you are looking for. This can also be found in [hcitool.c](https://github.com/aguedes/bluez/blob/master/tools/hcitool.c), at:-

> static void cmd_lescan(int dev_id, int argc, char **argv) {...}

2. Once your device is found, **connect** to the device. The source for this can be found at [hcitool.c](https://github.com/aguedes/bluez/blob/master/tools/hcitool.c), at:-

> static void cmd_lecc(int dev_id, int argc, char **argv)
>   {...}

3. You need to then do a **characteristic discovery** to look for the characteristic handle since you know the UUID. If your device is using the adopted battery service, then the characteristic you are looking for is [2A19](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.battery_level.xml). The code for the characteristic discovery can be found at [gatttool.c](https://github.com/aguedes/bluez/blob/master/attrib/gatttool.c), at:-

> static gboolean characteristics(gpointer user_data) {...}

4. Knowing the handle, you then proceed to **read the characteristic value**. The code for this can be found in [gatttool.c](https://github.com/aguedes/bluez/blob/master/attrib/gatttool.c), at:-

> static void char_read_cb(guint8 status, const guint8 *pdu, guint16 plen, gpointer user_data) {...}

Alternatively, you can just read the characteristic data using the characteristic UUID if you already know it. This can be found in [gatttool.c](https://github.com/aguedes/bluez/blob/master/attrib/gatttool.c), at:-

> static void char_read_by_uuid_cb(guint8 status, const guint8 *pdu,
>   guint16 plen, gpointer user_data)

If you're new to BlueZ, I recommend starting from the [BlueZ command line tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835469/using-bluetooth-low-energy-in-linux-command-line?noredirect=1&lq=1). This would help you understand more about what is going on under the hood in the source. To achieve what you want through the command line tools you simply need:-

```
- hcitool lescan
- gatttool -b 00:11:22:33:44:55 --characteristics 
- gatttool -b 00:11:22:33:44:55 --char-read --uuid=0x2A19
```

Where 00:11:22:33:44:55 should be replaced with the device address with the battery service.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks alot @yousif saeed : Could you tell how can I get the argument gpointer user_data of 'characteristics' function you mentioned above ?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the examples would suggest you to extract source code from Bluez to read GATT characteristics. [gattlib](https://github.com/labapart/gattlib) (C-library) does not require you to do so and is built on top of Bluez.

The library has two examples you could use for reading battery level.

You can use the [`notification` example](https://github.com/labapart/gattlib/blob/master/examples/notification/notification.c) that subscribe to battery level notification. Or you could use the [`read_write` example](https://github.com/labapart/gattlib/blob/master/examples/read_write/read_write.c) to read the battery level.