# Bluetooth Low Energy: Reading Fitbit Zip Data from Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I have a Fitbit Zip and I want to extract its data from Raspberry Pi using gatttool.

I can connect to it, figure out RX, TX handle etc. I understand I need to enable listen to the CCC handle like this

**char-write-req 0x000c 0100 --listen**

But before that, I need to enable reading the sensor (or series of action) through the TX handle, something like below.

**char-write-cmd 0x000b**

I am not sure how to figure out that  or the series of action that needs to be done before I can listen. Can anyone please help?

Comment: What service do you want to listen to?

Comment: I want to read the steps taken

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666294/how-can-i-connect-to-the-fitbit-zip-over-bluetooth-4-0-le-on-linux-with-bluez/16905668

Comment: @TimTisdall checked that before. Doesn't help. I was looking into [fitbitfun](https://github.com/cmwdotme/fitbitfun/blob/master/FitbitTestApp/FitbitDevice.m). Seems I need to write C01003 to RX handle for microdump. But that does't help. 
**char-write-cmd 0x000e C01003**    
**char-write-req 0x000c 0100 --listen**

Comment: @lilyhack unfortunately I haven't gotten any farther than that posting and haven't had any time to look at it since.  Please come back and post an answer if you get any farther!