# Can connect to BLE device with hcitool but not gatttool?

Tags: linux, qt, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluez

I am trying to connect to a bluetooth low energy device from my PC and Raspberry Pi3 in a QT application, but I get this QT error when trying to connect:

```
qt.bluetooth.bluez: Unknown l2cp socket error:  QBluetoothSocket::UnknownSocketError "Transport endpoint is not connected"
qt.bluetooth.bluez: void QBluetoothSocketPrivate::_q_readNotify() 14 error: -1 "Resource temporarily unavailable"
qt.bluetooth.bluez: Unknown l2cp socket error:  QBluetoothSocket::UnknownSocketError "Resource temporarily unavailable"
```

I don't think its QT, I suspect bluez is the problem. I found out that Linux can find the device with:

```
sudo hcitool lescan
```

And it can connect through:

```
sudo hcitool lecc <address>
```

So that's good. Problem is that as soon as I try with gatttool (which must be the eqavelent of what QT is trying to do), I get the following:

```
pi@user:~$ sudo gatttool -I 
[                 ][LE]> connect <address>
Attempting to connect to <address>
Error: connect error: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
[<address>][LE]>
```

The results are the some on both PC and Raspberry. bluez version on PC is 5.37 and on raspberry 5.23.

Any ideas? :(

Comment: This link will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657007/bluetooth-low-energy-listening-for-notifications-indications-in-linux . As per the post, you need to use gatttool -b <address> -I

Comment: a bit late for a reply...Every time they update bluez/bluetooth kernel they break something else.  I believe when you use gatttool the kernel gets involved in the connection and does a lot of other stuff,  but when you use hcitool it does a hci command.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Gatttool:**

Try with type `random` and most possibly it will work if there is no issue.

```
sudo gatttool -I -t random
```

You can bind to Bluetooth address in a single command itself.

```
sudo gatttool -I -t random -b <mac address>
```

**Using Hcitool:**

```
sudo hcitool lecc --random <mac address>
```

You can see the detailed HCI sniff log in another terminal while you are executing

```
sudo hcidump -X
```

Comment: Thanks for advice. But Do you have ideal step for hcitool for connecting the ble device. So I can simply follow that steps and if I get problem I need to debug but the steps are ideal so should not confuse in steps.