# BLE: bluetoothd crash [Software caused connection abort (103)]

Tags: bluez

- In BlueZ5.50/5.49 bluethood crash few second later while register for
     notification (BLE ).this issuse occurs only bluez5.49 and bluez5.50 .

  **#gattc register_for_notification 2 48:d0:cf:ff:d1:ad {1812,4,1} {2a4d,4}**

*bluetoothd[8728]: android/gatt.c:disconnected_cb() Software caused connection abort (103)*

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

0x000000000045ea56 in queue_remove_if (queue=0x6bf610, function=function@entry=0x43a2e0 , user_data=user_data@entry=0x6c3840) at src/shared/queue.c:292

292                     if (function(entry->data, user_data)) {

(gdb)

Comment: (gdb) p *queue
$3 = {ref_count = 32, head = 0x31, tail = 0x6bee70, entries = 7090960}
head is not a valid address

Comment: Have you tried the same operation using gatttool or bluetoothctl? I would recommend using these tools as they are more mature on Linux and therefore there's better chance of them passing. For details on using gatttool, see this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657007/bluetooth-low-energy-listening-for-notifications-indications-in-linux), and for details on using bluetoothctl, see this (https://mcuoneclipse.com/2016/12/19/tutorial-ble-pairing-the-raspberry-pi-3-model-b-with-hexiwear/).

Comment: agree with your point , same set of API call i am using in my application