GATTTool fails to read characteristics/attribute for Heart Beat data
I'm trying to read the heart rate data from my Xiaomi Mi Band 8 using BlueZ's gatttool. The heart rate data is found in the characteristic with UUID 0x2a37, which has the property NOTIFY.
However, when I attempt to read this characteristic, I receive the following error:
Error: Characteristic value/descriptor read failed: Attribute can't be read

Here's what I've done so far:
Discover all characteristic descriptors:
[AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF][LE]> char-desc 0x0025 0xffff
handle: 0x0026, uuid: 00002a37-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb  (Heart Rate Measurement characteristic)
handle: 0x0027, uuid: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb  (Client Characteristic Configuration Descriptor)

Enabled notifications for the heart rate measurement characteristic:
[AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF][LE]> char-write-req 0x0026 0100
Characteristic value was written successfully

However, I do not receive any notifications after performing these steps. I ensured that the fitness tracker is properly worn and active in measuring heart rate.
Tried to read Heart Beat Data
[AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF][LE]> char-read-hnd 0x0026
Error: Characteristic value/descriptor read failed: Attribute can't be read

Why can't I receive heart rate notifications from my Xiaomi Mi Band 8, and how can I successfully get the heart rate data using gatttool?
Any help will be appreciated.

gatttool was deprecated back in 2017. You should be able to enable notifications and read the value using the supported bluetoothctl tool.

To configure the Heart Rate Measurement characteristic you must write the Client Characteristic Configuration Descriptor.
To enable notifications, you must issue this:
[AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF][LE]> char-write-req 0x0027 0100


I have tried to enable the nofications by issuing the above commands. I dont see any notifications for a few minutes before the device got disconnencted. Please advise @risto.

Have you changed your setup and therefore a handle changed too? It generally looks like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21164886/8124605
